# Unit Testing a Constructor for a Singleton Object in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to unit test my constructor however due to a Task block, I am getting a false result for my unit test due to not testing the code that runs asynchronously. The hard part I found is testing the asynchronous code for this singleton object constructor.

Below is the unit test:

```swift
func testPermissionsManagerConstructor() {
    permissions = PermissionsManager

    XCTAssertTrue(permissions.isCameraAllowed)
    XCTAssertTrue(permissions.isMicrophoneAllowed)
    XCTAssertTrue(permissions.isLocationAllowed)
    XCTAssertTrue(permissions.isNotificationAllowed)
}
```

Below is the constructor for PermissionsManager:

```swift
private init() {
    // Checking for the enablement of FaceID.

    guard localAuthenticationContext.canEvaluatePolicy( .deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error ) else {
        print( error?.localizedDescription ?? "Can't evaluate policy" )

        if( error?.localizedDescription == "Biometry is not enrolled." ) {
            isNotEnrolledInFaceID = true
        }
        else if( error?.localizedDescription == "Biometry is not available." ) {
            isNotAvailableForFaceID = true
        }

        return
    }

    // Checking for other permissions. If ALL (camera, microphone, notifications, and location)
    // have been granted, the user will bypass the Permissions page.

    // Camera and Microphone
    isCameraAllowed = ( AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus( for: .video ) == .authorized )
    isMicrophoneAllowed = ( AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus( for: .audio ) == .authorized )

    Task {
        // Notifications
        let settings: UNNotificationSettings
        await settings = UNUserNotificationCenter.current().notificationSettings()
        isNotificationAllowed = ( settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized )
    }

    // Location
    let locationStatus = LocationManager.shared.checkPermissions()
    isLocationAllowed = locationStatus == .authorizedAlways || locationStatus == .authorizedWhenInUse
}
```

My first though was to use expectations but currently am unsure if this is the correct approach to take for this specific scenario.